# JavaFXでアプリケーションから自分と同じアプリケーションを別プロセスで呼び出したい

Tags: javafx

**環境**
OS: Windows10
JDK: JDK-11

**やりたいこと**
ExcelでWorkbookを編集中に、`ファイル->新規`, `ファイル->開く`を行うと、別プロセスのExcelが立ち上がります。こういった動作をJavaFXのアプリケーションで行いたいのですが方法がわかりません。

自身のjarのPATHを何かで取得して、Processクラスで呼び出すという方法しかないでしょうか？
アプリケーションはjavapackagerでexe化して配布するつもりです。

Comment: Excelがworkbookを別ウィンドウで開くようになったのは[Excel2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/office_client_development_support_blog/2016/12/19/excel2013-changes-to-sdi/)からのようです。ところでやりたいことは本当に別プロセスでウィンドウを立ち上げることなのでしょうか。リンク先でいうところのSDIが真に実現したいことなのであれば、1プロセスでも実現は可能です(リンク先にある通り、質問に書かれているExcel操作では、実際には別プロセスで無く同じプロセスで開かれていると思います)。

Comment: タスクマネージャーで確認しました。EXCEL.exeを複数回起動すると別プロセスになりますが、`ファイル->開く`だと確かに1プロセスですね。MDI, SDIという用語は初めて知りました。勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

試していないのでわかりませんが，新しくstageを作製したら新規ウィンドウが立ち上がったりしませんか？
例えばですが

```
@FXML
void onClickAction(ActionEvent event){
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("<fxmlファイルのパス>");
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Stage newStage = new Stage();
    newStage.setScene(scene);
    newStage.showAndWait();
}
```

みたいな感じで，新しいstageを作ってあげる方法です．
もし，fxmlではなくjavaファイルにpaneをコーディングしている場合でも，とりあえずSceneインスタンスさえ作製できればstageに突っ込むだけでなんとかなると思います．

Comment: 試してみたところ、所望の動作が実装できそうなことがわかりました。 起動時に渡されるprimaryStageがRootの役割になっていると思っていたのですが、完全に独立したウインドウになるのですね。ありがとうございました。